# Restlet not posting

Tags: jquery, post, restlet

I'm attempting to do a simple post in Restlet.

What's happening is I'm clicking on the link that shows up in my index.html, and when I go to my server output, it shows that I'm hitting urls, but it's never entering my @Post method. I seem to be following the tutorials correctly, but obviously something is amiss here.

If I change things to get instead of post, I can use them in the URL and it works just fine. But I'd really like to send things through post instead of get.

*How do I make Restlet feed into my post procedure?*

Update 1:

Since it appears the data I'm passing in for parameters is a json object, I tried changing the `@Post` to `@Post("json")` but it didn't make any change...

Below is a code dump of relevant pieces, since I'm sure at least one of them will be of interest. I'll be tracking this for followup questions. Thanks!

#### Begin code dump:

Here's my "index.html", shameless adapated from the jquery tutorial (to give an indicator to my javascript experience).

```
<html>                                                                  
  <head>                                                                  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
    <script type="text/javascript">                                         
      function doit() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.post(
            "http://localhost:15627/system/create",
             { key: "something here", auth: "happy", name: "The name" },
             function(data) {
               alert("Response: " + data);
             }
          );
        });
      }
    </script>                                                               
  </head>                                                               
  <body>                                                                  
    <a href="javascript:doit()">Link</a>
  </body>                                                                 
</html>
```

Now in my Java restlet, I have a very simple setup

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 15627);
    
    startDatabase();
    
    Application main = new Main();
    
    component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(main);
    component.start();
}

private Engine engine;

public Main() {
    this.engine = new Engine();
}
```

And my inbound root

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    // Create a root router
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    
    router.attach("/system/knock", new Knock(engine));
    router.attach("/system/create", new CreatePlayer(engine));
    
    return router;
}
```

And my create player routine

```
@Post
public Representation create(Representation rep) {
    Representation response = null;
    Form form = new Form(rep);
    
    String key = form.getFirstValue("key");
    String auth = form.getFirstValue("auth");
    String name = form.getFirstValue("name");
    
    System.out.println("Creating " + key + " " + auth + " " + name);
    
    String result = engine.create(key,auth,name);
    
    response = new StringRepresentation(result,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    return response;
}
```

Result of a call

```
Oct 12, 2011 3:32:23 PM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2011-10-12    15:32:23    127.0.0.1   -   -   15627   OPTIONS /system/create  -   200 0   0   0   http://localhost:15627  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)   -
```

Curling (following advice found here [Restlet POST using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033132/restlet-post-using-json/4785418#4785418)

```
C:\programs\curl>curl -X POST localhost:15627/system/create -H "Content-Type: ap
plication/json" -d '{"key" : "something", "auth" : "happy", "name" : "The name"}
'
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: something,; Host not found
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: auth; Host not found
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: happy,; Host not found
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name; Host not found
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 9

C:\programs\curl>
```

And the restlet output from the curl

```
Oct 12, 2011 3:43:47 PM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2011-10-12    15:43:47    127.0.0.1   -   -   15627   POST    /system/create  -   200 0   5   0   http://localhost:15627  curl/7.22.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5    -
```

Update 2:

I added a `handle(Request req, Response res)` method and that is currently responding to both gets and posts when I try to curl. In either case it isn't able to pull any data associated with it.

Comment: 2 suggestions: 1) post the output from your Restlet app so that we can see what it is logging when you make the POST call (it might be 404'ing), and 2) use `curl` to make the POST call manually from the command line (which will at least remove jQuery from the equation. Splitting the problem in half like that will help you figure out if whether it's a Restlet or jQuery issue.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your reply. I've added the result of a call. As far as curling, I'm on a windows system. Any thoughts how I might accomplish that? Honestly, I don't care about jquery - my END application will be in flash or java or something. At this point I'm only concerned about the server side of things. So if there's a better way to test it than using jQuery, I'd rather use it!

Comment: @Brian I've added the results of my `curl`.

Comment: Your curl command is getting hosed because of the quote characters on the command line. You should put the JSON into a file and pass it in using the -F or -d options (and the @ symbol to specify the source file name). See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up getting it to work. Instead of using a Restlet, I needed to use a ServerResource. Here's my solution

```
public class CreatePlayer extends ServerResource {

    private Engine engine; 

    public CreatePlayer() {
        this(Main.getEngine());
    }

    public CreatePlayer(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    @Post
    public Representation create(Representation rep) {
        System.err.println("Inside create");
        Form form = new Form(rep);

        String key = form.getFirstValue("key");
        String auth = form.getFirstValue("auth");
        String name = form.getFirstValue("name");

        System.err.println("Creating " + key + " " + auth + " " + name);

        String result = engine.create(key,auth,name);

        return new StringRepresentation(result,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    }

}
```

And my new inbound root:

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    // Create a root router
    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    router.attach("/homage/knock", Knock.class);
    router.attach("/homage/create", CreatePlayer.class);

    return router;
}
```

update 3:

To test it, I switched away from jquery, and from curl, and went with a java test driver. I'm able to get everything in when I do this, except that my driver, for whatever reason, isn't able to make multiple values. So if I do `name=foo&auth=happy" it gives me a variable`name`and a value of`foo&auth=happy`. So this is obviously an artifact of my driver not posting properly, which is good enough for me. I'm confident that the front end side of things will be capable of making a properly formatted post. If all else fails, I can hack it to put any variables I need into one and split it up. Less desirable, but it would work for now.

I appreciate all the help, folks!

Answer (score 2):

A few things: Your Content-type is JSON but on the server you are trying to create a Form Representation. You need to use JSONRepresentation class for that by initializing with the `rep` argument of the `@Post` function

Why you are getting a 200 response as per the Restlet log: Probably because all the form values are empty/null and it may be that your create player is working with null values - check for that and you'll see it may be the case.

Yes, `@Post("json")` is good but of no use if you are not processing your incoming representation as JSON...

What is unknown: Are you even getting any response in your alert? What is the value that is being returned? undefined??

Just for your benefit try using `$.ajax` and make things explicit and you'll probably realize where you may be faltering, sometimes the shorthand short circuits some errors...once you are adept at it, it'll help using the short hands. I for one have never been able to think in shorthand properly and more so I prefer uniformity in code - there is no `$.delete` or `$.put` so I just use `$.ajax` (This is only for information, nothing to do with the problem...)

Try these out and see if it works...