# What Restlet(Java) libraries are needed for JSON GET/POST?

Tags: java, json, restlet, restlet-2.0

*This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033132/restlet-post-using-json), which was written in 2010. Now that things may have changed in 2017, I think this is a great opportunity to re-ask the question.*

---

#### What libraries are needed?

Using `org.restlet.jee 2.3.10`, I have noticed that there are several libraries which could support JSON. Here are some names from the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.restlet.jee):

- `org.restlet.ext.jackson`
- `org.restlet.ext.json`
- `org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json`
- `org.restlet.lib.org.json`

What is the current recommended / standard way of GET-ing and POST-ing JSON-formatted text?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like: "`org.restlet.JSON`".
You can see the official tutorial [here](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/editions/gwt/json).

Comment: Isn't that, like, for the Google Web Toolkit framework?